# let $f$ and $g$ be two functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ with $f$ strictly increasing. Which of the follwing is true?

Tags: functions, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

let  $f$ and $g$ be two  functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ with $f$ strictly increasing.  Which of the follwing is true?

> > (a). If $g$ is continuous, then $f\circ g$ is continuous.
> >
> > (b).  If $f$ is continuous, then $f\circ g$ is continuous.
> >
> > (c). If $f$ and $f\circ g$ are continuous, then $g$ is continuous.
> >
> > (d). If $g$ and $f\circ g$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

**I guessed this**

$f$ is strictly increasing $\implies$ $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ So, If $g$ is continuous then $f\circ g$ is continuous. Is my approach is correct? 
If i am right, why the others are wrong? can you give a counter examples for that?

Comment: Should there be a difference between (a) and (b)?

Comment: $f$ strictly increasing doesn't imply $f$ is continuous: I'm thinking of a function with 1 or more jump discontinuities 'upwards' and increasing on each segment.

Comment: $f(x)=x+1$ if $0\leq x$, $f(x)=x-1$ if $x<0$.
As you see f is strictly increasing but not continuous.

Answer (score 8):

Only statement (c) is true.

**Hint:** if $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, it has a continuous (left-)inverse $f^{-1}$.  Consider $f^{-1} \circ f \circ g$.

---

Counterexamples, in no particular order:

- $f(x) = x$, $g(x)$ is discontinuous
- $f$ is increasing but discontinuous, $g$ is a constant function
- $f$ is increasing but discontinuous, $g(x) = x$

---

An example of a strictly increasing discontinuous function:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x/3 & x \in [0,1/2)\\
(x+1)/3 & x \in [1/2,1]
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: what is continuous inverse? It is new to me. Kindly explain. It doesnt need one-one?@omnomnomnom

Comment: @gloom I'm saying that since $f$ is strictly increasing, it is one-to-one, and there is a continuous function $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$.

Comment: oh.. thank you ..@Omnomnomnom

Comment: @Omnomnomnom) : Why option (D) is incorrect ? As $g$ is strictly increasing so $g^{-1}$ exists and continuous and then $f\circ g \circ g^{-1}=f$ is also continuous. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @S.P yes, you're wrong. First, the question does not say that g is strictly increasing. Second, even in the case that $g$ is strictly increasing, we can take $g(x)=x/3$ and $f(x)$ as in the discontinuous example above. Note that $g$ has a left-inverse, but not a right inverse.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom) : Yes.. I misread the question..One more question : As $f$ is strictly increasing so $f^{-1}$ exists ...it is ok..but why  $f^{-1}$ is continuous ? I also can't understand what do you mean by left-inverse and right-inverse...Please explain it..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Whenever $f$ is strictly increasing, there is a function $f^{-1}$ for which $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$.  It is not necessarily true, however, that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$.  That is, $f^{-1}$ acts as the inverse of $f$ from the *left*, but not from the right.

Comment: The "geometric" justification for the continuity of $f^{-1}$ is that the graph is simply a reflection through $y = x$, so of course the reflected graph will be a "continuous graph" (i.e. will be path connected).

Comment: For a rigorous proof that $f^{-1}$ must be continuous, see [problem 45 here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~punshs/Analysis-Solutions/HW3-Sol.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is strictly increasing, we can guarantee that $f$ has, at most, countably infinitely many points of discontinuity. But strict monotonicity does not imply continuity at all. Consider $f(x)=x/2$ for $x<1/2$ and $f(x)=(1+x)/2$ for $x\ge1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), consider $g(x) = x$ and $f$ any discontinuous increasing function (for example $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}x, x > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$).

For (b), consider $f(x) = x$ and $g$ any discontinuous function.

For (d), consider $g(x) = 0$ and $f$ any discontinuous increasing function.

Comment: f(0) cannot be -1.

Comment: Oh, of course. My bad.